# How to use ppx.metaquot in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ppx

The command written in [README.md](https://github.com/alainfrisch/ppx_tools) doesn't work (The usage of ocamlfind is shown.) I understand the ppx_metaquot execution file is a kind of rewrite file, so I can translate my code using quasi quotation in this way:

```
ocamlfind ppx_tools/rewriter ~/.opam/system/lib/ppx_tools/ppx_metaquot  sample.ml
```

but this may not be an assumed way, so please tell me the correct usage.

Answer (score 2):

When wd want to use some PPX, normally wd use `-package` option of ocamlfind:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package ppx_tools.metaquot sample.ml
```

This compiles `sample.ml` using the preprocessor `ppx_tools.metaquot`.

If you want to see the output of PPX in human readable form, AFAIK things get a bit more complicated.:

```
ocamlfind ppx_tools/rewriter -ppx ~/.opam/system/lib/ppx_tools/ppx_metaquot sample.ml
```

or the following is better:

```
ocamlfind ppx_tools/rewriter -ppx `ocamlfind query ppx_tools`/ppx_metaquot sample.ml
```

There might be a simpler way than this but I do not know.

Comment: Thank you, but in my environment, some error occurs using ocamlc:

    sh: ppx_tools.metaquot: command not found
    File "mpr.ml", line 1:
    Error: Error while running external preprocessor
    Command line: ppx_tools.metaquot '/var/folders/gk/5tlptk8j44751wj4bw_2lzm00000gn/T/camlppxb52f14' '/var/folders/gk/5tlptk8j44751wj4bw_2lzm00000gn/T/camlppx459e01'

Comment: Ah, sorrry, I made a typo.  `ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package ppx_tools.metaquot sample.ml` is the correct one. I fix the answer part too.

Comment: oh, I see, ppx can also be used as a package, thank you.